# How can I get a log of commits according to the time they were pushed?

Tags: python, git, git-log

Using Python, the following command

```
log = subprocess.check_output(['git','-C',ProjectPath, 'log', '--graph', '--pretty=format:%h -%d %s (%cr) <%an>', '--abbrev-commit', '--after', lastSuccesBuild])
```

gives commit logs from `lastSuccessfulBuild` date (for example from `1.3.15`) up to the last `git pull` (for example, today).

However, if one of the developers pushes today (`29.3.15`) all commits (for example from `1.2.15`), I see logs only from `lastSuccessfulBuild(today)`.

How can I get all commits logs according to the *push time* instead of the commit time (so I would not miss the earlier commits log)?

My environment: 
Git server and Jenkins are separate machines.

Comment: You would need a server side hook to record the push times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short, but definite answer: **Git itself doesn't record push times**.

In other words, no combination of Git commands will tell you at what time someone pushed to the remote.